# Title attribute for react native <View>, <TouchableOpacity> same as that of <div titile="abc">

Tags: html, reactjs, react-native, view

We are using react native for creating web UI as well. Here my requirement is to pass title attribute in `<View/>` or `<Text/>` component same as that of `<div title="abc">` tag in HTML. Could someone please suggest and help me out.

Comment: Hi. Have you found a way? Cause title attribute is not passed to div when converting to Web.

Comment: Hi, I have found a way for this:
Let suppose you wan to pass title attribute to <TouchableOpacity> then assign ref and in your useEffect you have to call ref.current.setNativeProps({title}). whatever title you want to pass here.

Comment: Thanks, that's how I planned to do it, directly for web. But setNativeProps seems cool.

Answer (score -1):

```
<View>
  <Text>ABC</Text>
<View/>
```

Something like this.

If it needs to be a variable (and it is called title):

```
<View>
  <Text>{title}</Text>
<View/>
```

Same goes for TouchableOpacity.

Comment: I have asked for title attribute not a title prop.

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by using the title attribute for "View"?
[here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view) you can find every prop that "View" accepts.

Also, you can find out which props are going to use for the other React native Components, in the same way.

I think you want to know how to send params like the title to a component that we create on our own, like a container in our app:

```
// Container.js
import ...
.
.
.
const Container = (props) => {
 // Destructuring the props
 const {title, children} = props;
 return (
  <View style = {styles.container}>
   <View style = {styles.header}> // header of your container
     <Text>{title}</Text> // use title here
   </View>
  {children} // body of your container
  </View>
 )
}
export default Container;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 // styles here
})

// Home.js
import ...
import Container from './Container.js'
.
.
.
const Home = (props) => {
 return(
  <Container title = 'Home'> // now we can send this param to our Container
  // body as Container Children goes here
  </Container>
 )
}
```

Comment: When user hover on a div tag in browser it show what is it's title which we pass in <div title="abc"/> kind of. It comes as a tooltip.